# mediaplayer with a list of audio that load asynchronously

Tags: android, android-asynctask, media-player

I have a Music Player application that should play music via online streaming. It has a list of audio titles, and a play button and progress bar. upon clicking on a list item, it executes an asyncTask which loads the datasource in the mediaplayer from url and prepares it.

heres the list item click listener:

```
        leclistv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int p, long arg3)
            { 
                url=geturl(p);
                new PrepareStream().execute(url);
            }

        });
```

the asynctask class:

```
class PrepareStream extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... opath) {
        try {
            String url = new String(opath[0]);
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();       
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);
        updateProgressBar();
        progress.dismiss();

    }
}
```

BUT this works only once. once when i click on any list item, it loads just fine and plays just fine. but for the second time if i click on any list item, it crashes - because an asyncTask can be used only once. is there any way to make it work each time? if not, is there an alternative way to do this?

P.S: i could do it in a simple way without using asynctask, but i had to use because the audio is loaded from the server so the prepare() takes time and therefore i need to show the progressDialog while its loading.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation for media player and how to handle varies problem related to it..[reference link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

reference code from the above link

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        mMediaPlayer = ... // initialize it here
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
    }
}

/** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    //When Media prepare this method work and you start your player
    player.start();
}
 }
```

Comment: i read this. but i still dont know what to use. i tried simple prepareAsync() but it doesn't work